# How to quickly test Windows Gadgets?

Tags: windows, testing, windows-7, desktop, windows-desktop-gadgets

How should one **quickly test** a **Windows Gadget** during development? Creating the archive, installing it and adding it to the desktop every time is extremely tedious...

Comment: may be, write a script that automatically archive the windows gadget files, install, and add it to your desktop?

Comment: This would be the last resort, but you'd think Microsoft would have thought of the poor gadget developers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This application might speed up the process:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/gadgets/GadgetPacker.aspx

Whilst developing a desktop gadget for Windows 7, it became apparent how much of a pain it was going through the build process. I decided it would be a lot easier to write a simple automation tool, to take care of the necessary steps. This would speed up the overall developing and testing phase.

---

This article might also be helpfull

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-debug-a-windows-vista-sidebar-gadget-with-visual-studio/

Comment: Neat tool, thanks for your answer! I still find it hard to believe that Microsoft proposes absolutely nothing to help developers... Not to mention that the API is terrible and doesn't work well.

Answer (score 2):

After you've installed it once, you can actually manipulate the installed version's source code files directly. It should be installed at

C:\Users\ **YourUserName** \AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Sidebar\Gadgets\ **GadgetName.gadget** \

Then, each time you make changes to the source code found there you just need to add a new instance of the gadget to your desktop. I just keep the Gadget Gallery open and drag a new instance after I've saved a new change.